# Is there documentation or an SDK for Microsoft Edge extensions yet?

Tags: javascript, windows-10, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

Is there any published documentation or an SDK for writing extensions for Microsoft Edge? If so, I can't find it. If not, is there an ETA when this might be available? It would be nice to get a jump on this before the Windows 10 release.

Comment: I still haven't seen anything... hmmmm.....

Comment: this video can be helpful : https://channel9.msdn.com/events/WebPlatformSummit/edgesummit2016/ES1614

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is now an API with all the wonderful documentation thereunto appertaining: [Microsoft Edge API reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/apireference/)

---

Old Answer:

In short, no, not yet.

Your best bet for this is to visit [Microsoft's website](http://dev.modern.ie/) for the browser, which has sections devoted to developers. They have a [roadmap for feature support](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/), as well.

As of [their latest rundown](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/), Microsoft Edge will not support extensions on day one of Windows 10's release, and there's no exact date or ETA on when they will arrive. Current estimates point to sometime *after* the first big update, which means  [sometime in 2016](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/10/microsoft-edge-wont-get-chrome-like-extensions-until-2016/).

What we *do* know is that previous extension methods, such as ActiveX and BrowserHelperObjects (BHOs) will **not** be supported in Edge. Instead, Microsoft is moving toward Chrome-like extensions, which rely heavily on HTML and JavaScript.

Also, browser extension support on Windows 10 Mobile will be coming later this fall, which means we can assume extensions for Edge on Windows 10 will be enabled and documented before that time.

There is a [hands-on review](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/when-will-microsoft-s-edge-browser-get-extensions--1293644/2) by TechRadar that goes into a bit more depth regarding extensions, tabs, processes, memory management, and security, if you're interested in those topics.

(I have no affiliation with Microsoft or TechRadar)

Answer (score 6):

For up-to-date information, see [Microsoft-Edge-Extension Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/microsoft-edge-extension/info)

### Updated (05/12/2016)

Microsoft Edge has updated their documentation, including [Accessibility](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/accessibility/),[Internationalization](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/internationalization/), and etc.

### Updated (04/07/2016)

Microsoft Edge has released [Extension API roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/extension-api-roadmap/), [Supported apis](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/supported-apis/) and [Supported manifest keys](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/supported-manifest-keys/)

### Yesterday (3/17/2016),

[Microsoft Edge extension began to be available to preview](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/03/17/preview-extensions/)

> Today, we’re happy to announce that the first set of extensions for Microsoft Edge are now available to preview via the Windows Insider Program. You can try out extensions starting in build 14291, which was released today to the Fast ring.

For the documentation, there are limited resources public at present, take a look at [Microsoft Edge Extensions](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/).